# Django 1.4 - assertQuerysetEqual - how to use method

Tags: django, testing, django-queryset

I'm wondering how the TestCase.assertQuerysetEqual method works. I tried it in different ways, each of them leading me to another error message.

```
#create a backup of all records in the tree
tree_record_backup = list(Tree.objects.all())

#do some updates on another table, which should not affect the tree table if everything goes wrong

#check if list of tree records did not changed
tree_record_qs = Tree.objects.all()
#Number1:
self.assertQuerysetEqual(tree_record_qs,[repr(tree_record_backup)])
#Number2:
self.assertQuerysetEqual(tree_record_qs,tree_record_backup)
```

Error Message for Number1:

```
First list contains 21 additional elements.
First extra element 1:
node.pk: 2 - node: node2 - pk: 2 - level: 0 - ancestor: 2
```

Error Message for Number 2:

```
AssertionError: Lists differ: ['<Tree: node.pk: 1 - node: ro... != [<Tree: node.pk: 1 - node: roo...

First differing element 0:
<Tree: node.pk: 1 - node: root - pk: 1 - level: 0 - ancestor: 1>
node.pk: 1 - node: root - pk: 1 - level: 0 - ancestor: 1
```

Thanks for hints how to use the assertQuerysetEqual method correctly.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try this:

```
self.assertQuerysetEqual(
    tree_record_qs,
    [repr(r) for r in tree_record_backup]
)
```

it's a bit weird and undocumented; but, that should work for you.

Answer (score 36):

`assertQuerysetEqual` takes a `queryset`, a *list of values* and a `transform` callable which is called on the queryset to convert it into something comparable to the list of values. By default this callable is `repr`. This is kind of irritating since it doesn't actually compare two querysets, but the easy fix for most cases is using `map(repr, your_second_queryset)` for the list of values. This is [documented in django since version 1.3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.assertQuerysetEqual).

Comment: Using python 3 + django 1.5 you should to use `map(repr, your_second_queryset)` because assertQuerysetEqual converts queryset to a list.