# comparing querysets in django TestCase

Tags: django, compare, testcase, django-queryset

I have a very simple view as follows

```
def simple_view(request):
    documents = request.user.document_set.all()
    return render(request, 'simple.html', {'documents': documents})
```

To test the above view in my test case i have the following method which errors out.

```
Class SomeTestCase(TestCase):
    # ...
    def test_simple_view(self):
        # ... some other checks
        docset = self.resonse.context['documents']
        self.assertTrue(self.user.document_set.all() == docset) # This line raises an error
    # ...
```

The error i get is `AssertionError: False is not true`.
I have tried printing both the querysets and both are absolutely identical. Why would it return `False` when both the objects are identical ? Any Ideas ?

Currently to overcome this, I am using a nasty hack of checking lengths as follows:

```
ds1, ds2 = self.response.context['documents'], self.user.document_set.all()
self.assertTrue(len([x for x in ds1 if x in ds2]) == len(ds1) == len(ds2)) # Makes sure each entry in ds1 exists in ds2
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The queryset objects will not be identical if they are the result of different queries even if  they have the same values in their result (compare `ds1.query` and `ds2.query`).

If you convert the query set to a list first, you should be able to do a normal comparison (assuming they have the same sort order of course):

```
self.assertEqual(list(ds1), list(ds2))
```

Comment: Or slight more succinctly self.assertEqual(list(ds1), list(ds2))

Comment: If your querysets are too huge for evaluating then you probably can use django's 
[defer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#defer) or [only](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#only)

Comment: Perhaps we could use `set()`, instead of `list()`, to be independent of sort-order.

Comment: True, could put them in a set but that could also hide issues where one query set has duplicate rows while the other doesn't.

Comment: @MattiJohn: You're absolutely right. Actually I just ran into such an issue myself. I'll stick to `list()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

This alternative doesn't need sorting:

```
self.assertQuerysetEqual(qs1, list(qs2), ordered=False)
```

See the [assert reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.assertQuerySetEqual).

Note: Only for django 1.4+.

Comment: Tried this, but querysets are not equals all the time (even if they are the same)! Got it worked using: `self.assertQuerysetEqual(qs1, map(repr, qs2), ordered=False)`. From this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14189017/821594

Comment: @stalk I don't really know why... it's supposed to use `repr()` to compare by default. And if both quesysets are equal the repr is expected to be the same, right?

Comment: Looking at [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/testing/overview/#django.test.TestCase.assertQuerysetEqual) i thought, that your example will work. But it doesn't... Looks like `repr` func is applied only to first non-list queryset, and for the second list it must be applided explicitly. With django 1.4.5: `qs1 = M.objects.all(); qs2 = M.objects.all() # (the same)`, `self.assertQuerysetEqual(qs1, list(qs2), ordered=False)` <-- fails; `self.assertQuerysetEqual(qs1, map(repr, qs2), ordered=False)` <-- passes;

Comment: Yes `assertQuerySetEquals` fails in 2.1 even if the same queryset reference is passed e.g., `assertQuerySetEquals(qs1, qs1)`  -- but stalk's solution does work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [assertQuerySetEqual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.assertQuerysetEqual) method to compare two querysets without casting to a list.  This will return `True` if the values of the querysets are equal, regardless of if the queries are different.

One gotcha is that this method applies the `repr` function as a transform to each object in the first argument before comparing, which can result in the following error when comparing two actually equal querysets:

```
AssertionError: Lists differ: ['<Object: id1'] != [<Object: id1>]
```

The solution is to pass your own `transform` function to use instead of `repr`:

```
self.assertQuerySetEqual(qs1, qs2, transform=lambda x: x)
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to check that **Django querysets are completely the same**

`self.assertEqual(str(simple_qs.query), str(complex_qs.query))`

Answer (score 1):

For me works the `transform` option:

```
    def subject(self):
        return Mission.objects.add_keynest_api_token().filter(keynest_api_token__isnull=False)

    def test_mission_has_property(self):
        self.mission.appartement = self.property
        self.mission.save()
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(self.subject(), [self.mission], transform=lambda x: x)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to assert that the content of two querysets is equal without worrying about the order, use the following:

```py
self.assertQuerysetEqual(actual_queryset, expected_queryset, transform=lambda x: x, ordered=False)
```

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution. We need to convert `Querysets` to sorted lists before we can compare them. Something as follows.

```
Class SomeTestCase(TestCase):
    # ...
    def test_simple_view(self):
        # ... some other checks
        docset1 = self.resonse.context['documents']
        docset2 = self.user.document_set.all()
        self.assertTrue(list(sorted(docset1)) == len(sorted(docset)))
    # ...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def test_simple_view(self):
    # ... some other checks
    docset = set([i.pk for i in self.resonse.context['documents']])
    prev = set([i.pk for i in self.user.document_set.all()])
    diff = prev.difference(docset)
    self.assertTrue(len(diff)==0)
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.