# How do I test Django QuerySets are equal?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-testing

I am trying to test my Django views. This view passes a QuerySet to the template:

```
def merchant_home(request, slug):
  merchant = Merchant.objects.get(slug=slug)
  product_list = merchant.products.all()
  return render_to_response('merchant_home.html',
                            {'merchant': merchant,
                            'product_list': product_list},
                            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and test:

```
  def test(self):
    "Merchant home view should send merchant and merchant products to the template"
    merchant = Merchant.objects.create(name='test merchant')
    product = Product.objects.create(name='test product', price=100.00)
    merchant.products.add(product)

    test_client = Client()
    response = test_client.get('/' + merchant.slug)
    # self.assertListEqual(response.context['product_list'], merchant.products.all())
    self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['product_list'], merchant.products.all())
```

***EDIT*** 
I am using `self.assertQuerysetEqua`l instead of `self.assertListEqual`. Unfortunately this still doesn't work, and the terminal displays this: 
    `['<Product: Product object>'] != [<Product: Product object>]`

---

`assertListEqual` raises: `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'difference'` and
`assertEqual` does not work either, although `self.assertSetEqual(response.context['product_list'][0], merchant.products.all()[0])` does pass.

I assume this is because the QuerySets are different objects even though they contain the same model instances.

How do I test that two QuerySets contain the same data? I am even testing this correctly? This is my 4th day learning Django so I would like to know best practices, if possible. Thanks.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16059121

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use [assertQuerysetEqual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.assertQuerysetEqual), which is built to compare the two querysets for you. You will need to subclass Django's `django.test.TestCase` for it to be available in your tests.

Comment: Awesome, this is helpful, though now my tests fails because of this:
AssertionError: ['<Product: Product object>'] != [<Product: Product object>]
The only difference I see is that there are quotes around the first product object. They are both of class QuerySet

Answer (score 47):

By default `assertQuerysetEqual` uses `repr()` on the first argument. This is why you were having issues with the strings in the queryset comparison.

To work around this you can [override the `transform` argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.assertQuerysetEqual) with a `lambda` function that doesn't use `repr()`:

```
self.assertQuerysetEqual(queryset_1, queryset_2, transform=lambda x: x)
```

Comment: I found this also worked for comparing two dictionaries with the same keys and the same queryset values: `self.assertQuerysetEqual(dict_1, dict_2, transform=lambda x: x)`

Answer (score 11):

I just had the same problem. The second argument of `assertQuerysetEqual` needs to be a list of the expected repr()s as strings. Here is an example from the Django test suite:

```
self.assertQuerysetEqual(c1.tags.all(), ["<Tag: t1>", "<Tag: t2>"], ordered=False)
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14189017/678486 (full disclosure this is my answer).

Answer (score 4):

An alternative, but not necessarily better, method might look like this (testing context in a view, for example) when using pytest:

```
all_the_things = Things.objects.all()
assert set(response.context_data['all_the_things']) == set(all_the_things)
```

This converts it to a set, which is directly comparable with another set.  Be careful with the behaviour of `set` though, it might not be exactly what you want since it will remove duplicates and ignore the order of objects.

Comment: You probably do not need to use `set(list())`, `set()` would do.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up solving this issue using `map` to `repr()` each entry in the queryset inside the `self.assertQuerysetEqual` call, e.g.

```
self.assertQuerysetEqual(queryset_1, map(repr, queryset_2))
```

Comment: `AssertionError: <QuerySet [<Account: Test Account>]> != <map object at 0x10c7f7ac8>`

Answer (score -1):

I found that using `self.assertCountEqual(queryset1, queryset2)` also solves the issue.

Comment: This doesn't add anything substantial to the existing answers. I recommend upvoting those answers instead.