# Django 2.2 - Testing response context with assertQuerySetEqual fails

Tags: django, django-testing

Trying to test response context in Django TestCase with `assertQuerysetEqual`but it fails.

I tried printing count of `Country.objects.all().count()` and `response.context['countries'].count()`. both returns 1 as I create one record at start of the test.

Also tried `ordered=True` on assertion method but no luck still fails the test. Am I missing something or need do it other way?

View that returns response

```
class CountriesListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Country
    template_name = 'management/countries/countries.html'
    context_object_name = 'countries'
```

Test using

```
class CountryTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.countries_list_url = '/countries'

    def test_response_returns_countries_context(self):
        Country.objects.create(
            name='India',
            iso_3166_1='IN'
        )
        response = self.client.get(self.countries_list_url)

        self.assertQuerysetEqual(Country.objects.all(), response.context['countries'])
```

Error I'm getting

```
AssertionError: Lists differ: ['<Country: Country object (1)>'] != [<Country: Country object (1)>]

First differing element 0:
'<Country: Country object (1)>'
<Country: Country object (1)>

- ['<Country: Country object (1)>']
?  -                             -

+ [<Country: Country object (1)>]
```

Getting same error for

```
self.assertQuerysetEqual(Country.objects.all(), Country.objects.all())
```

Comment: so far noted string syntax in assertion error

Answer (score 1):

[Found solutions from other question which end up with similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49129560/6585436)

Solution was to use different transform function `transform=lambda x: x`

```
    def test_response_returns_countries_context(self):
        Country.objects.create(
            name='India',
            iso_3166_1='IN'
        )
        response = self.client.get(self.countries_list_url)

        self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['countries'], Country.objects.all(), transform=lambda x: x)
```