# Django test assert not equal

Tags: python, django, python-unittest

Trying to test selector layer im my app, but django dont pass simle test. Querysets looks quite similar, maybe i lost something.

**test.py**

```py
from django.test import TestCase

from books.models import Author, Book
from books.selectors import get_books


class SelectorTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.author = Author.objects.create(
            name='test_author'
        )
        self.book = Book.objects.create(
            name='test_book',
            category='Drama',
            release_date='2001-01-01',
            author=self.author,
            is_read=True
        )

    def test_get_books(self):
         self.assertEqual(get_books(), Book.objects.all())
```

**selectors.py**

```py
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet

from books.models import Book


def get_books() -> QuerySet[Book]:
    """
    Return all objects of Book model.
    """
    books = Book.objects.all()

    return books
```

**assertion error**

```py
AssertionError: <QuerySet [<Book: test_book>]> != <QuerySet [<Book: test_book>]>
```

Comment: There is simply no equality check implemented for a `QuerySet`...

Comment: Thanks. I should think how i need to test my service.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I test Django QuerySets are equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685023/how-do-i-test-django-querysets-are-equal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `TransactionTestCase.assertQuerysetEqual` assertion from Django's `TestCase` class. [Check the documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/tools/).

In your case:

```
    # …

    def test_get_books(self):
         self.assertQuerysetEqual(get_books(), Book.objects.all())
```

Answer (score 0):

To test that two querysets return the same objects but not necessarily in the same order (assuming both query the same underlying Model, of course):

```
qs1  = Book.objects.all()
qs2 = get_books()
pk1 = qs1.values_list( 'pk', flat=True)
pk2 = q2s.values_list( 'pk', flat=True)

self.assertEqual ( set(pk1), set(pk2) )
```

This makes a reasonably useful message when the test fails. You get the pks which are in one and not the other identified, not just a not equal" message.

I think if you use `list()` instead of `set()` you get to check that both return the same objects in the same order.