# Django: Compare two querysets

Tags: python, django

I have a model named Music and it has artist ManyToManyField. I want to validate that **artist** and **name** fields are *unique_together*. Django will not let to put ManyToManyField into the unique_together list of Meta class. Below is what I am doing and I is giving me an error

> <"Music: Hello> needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

```
class Music(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    artist = models.ManyToManyField(Performer, related_name='all_songs')
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='music/')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        similar_musics = self.__class__.objects.filter(name=self.name)
        for music in similar_musics:
            artists = music.artist.all()
            diff = set(artists.all()).difference(set(self.artist.all()))
            if diff:
                raise ValidationError('This song seems to be already created!')

        super(Music, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

What is the easiest way to validate so that artist and name fields unique together **?** 
Additionally, I want to compress music file and stream my compressed music to browser and in the browser uncompress received parts and play. So, it may be similar to **spotify** but very simple version. What may be best way to do this task? Thank you in advance

Comment: hi @UMAR, please dont ask more than one question in the same post, remember we are here to help you : )

Comment: Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16058571/comparing-querysets-in-django-testcase